# Nintendo DS and Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm, nintendo-ds, homebrew

i was wondering if DS`s hardware is capable of running a game that utilizes a feedforward neural network using genetic algorithms.
I know that this has to do with the implementation of the homebrew game as well as the nn and the ga, but i am curious...

(i know nothing about how the DS`s ARMs are used, etc, etc, etc)

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, devices like the Nintendo DS are plenty powerful enough for this sort of thing.  I haven't worked with the Nintendo DS specifically, but I have written a neural network character recognition app for a Windows Mobile smartphone, which is comparable in processing power.

As you mention, it all depends upon how you write it.  You could just as easily write something that *doesn't* work on the Nintendo DS.

Comment: For that matter, you could just as easily write something that doesn't run on a 16-core 128GB monster server either.

Comment: @n00ki3: "bwhahaha" is traditionally used when plotting to take over the world. I think you mean "LOL".